# phpunit run class without "test" in the name

Tags: php, laravel, annotations, phpunit

How to indicate to `phpunit` that the class is a test class?

The `/** @test */` annotation seems to work only for methods that don't have `test` string appended in their name

So how to run a test class without appending the `test` string to its name?

Here's the class

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
/** @test */
class RepoPost extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function postSave()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function anotherOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Running

```sh
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter RepoPost
```

Outputs

> No tests executed!

#### Update

Here's my `phpunit.xml` config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         colors="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory>./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

While it's possible to run the class via full path as [@Alister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6216/alister-bulman) pointed out like this

```sh
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/RepoPost.php
```

It isn't convenient to do this over and over for every class, especially as part of the CI process
Ideally the class would run within the full test suite by

```sh
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your phpunit.xml add the suffix attribute to the  tags. The example will run all `.php` files, which may become risky if you have any none TestCase classes/files in there which is why its convention to suffix the classes with `Test`.

```
<testsuite name="Feature">
    <directory suffix=".php">./tests/Feature</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gosh! I just needed the extension after all, thank you

Comment: btw all classes in that folder are tests, so it's not really risky

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't read a class-level `/** @test */` annotation, but a default phpunit.xml file does also has the testsuite defined with a filename suffix:

```
 <testsuites>
     <testsuite name="default">
         <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
     </testsuite>
 </testsuites>
```

If you run phpunit on the specific file: `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/RepoPost.php` it does run the tests, even if the filename does not match the suffix.

Comment: Running the test via the full path does work, but removing the suffix restriction from phpunit doesn't take effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use suffix:

```
 <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
```

Then you should rename your file to be `RepoPostTest.php`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I might not have been clear, I'm interested to know if there's a way to do it without renaming the file like we do with methods